# Repeatedly getting "Failed to copy full contents from..." when running "mvn clean install" even after adjusting permissions

Tags: macos, maven

I'm running an inherited project and it seems to *sometimes* work, but for what seems like 99% of the time, I get the `Failed to copy full contents from...` error which I have found to be attributable to folder permissions.

I've used `chmod` recursively to set the parent folder and its children to 777, but when I run `mvn clean install -DskipTests`, it removes the `target` folder and replaces it with a new `target` folder with apparently read-only access.

Is there a way to make it so it just knows to create the child folder with `read-write` access when creating it? I feel as though I'm missing something here.

Edit: I should also point out that sometimes (only SOMEtimes), the mvn operation succeeds when I delete the `target` folder. Any idea how this works only sometimes?

Comment: Could you describe your environment? I see a similar issue on Windows 10 Pro when developing inside a Maven Docker container.

Comment: Did you find a solution or workaround?